# ngrx state is undefined

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm attempting to encapsulate my ngrx state in a shared service class to abstract the implementation details away from my components.

Example service class that is registered in my app.module.ts `providers`

```
@Injectable()
export class PatientService {

  state: Observable<PatientState>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>,
  ) {
    this.state = store.select<PatientState>('patients');
  }

}
```

I have verified my actions, reducer and effects are working as expected, however, when I subscribe to the service state in a component, it returns `undefined`.

Example component subscription using the shared service:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private patientService: PatientService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // dispatches action to load patient from API
    this.patientService.loadPatient();

    this.patientService.state.subscribe(patientState => {
        console.log('patientState', patientState);
        // Does not work. Logs undefined.
    });
  }

}
```

If I subscribe directly to the store, it works as expected.

Example:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private patientActions: PatientActions,
    private store: Store<AppState>,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(this.patientActions.loadPatient());

    this.store.select<PatientState>('patients').subscribe(patientState => {
        console.log('patientState', patientState);
        // Works as expected.
    });
  }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I had the similar issue: when a component subscribes to state it gets `state === undefined` always. It was very confused for me, but finally I've found corresponding reducer is not implemented magic code: `default: return state;`. Hope it'll help to somebody

Answer (score 6):

I solved this by following [Mergasov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742967/ngrx-state-is-undefined#comment77463950_42742967)'s advice and set a default case condtion:

> I had the similar issue: when a component subscribes to state it gets `state === undefined` always. It was very confused for me, but finally I've found corresponding reducer is not implemented magic code: `default: return state;`

Here's how that looks in the context of a larger `reducer.ts`:

```
  export function reducer(state: EntityState= initialEntityState, action:  actions.EntityAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case actions.CREATE_ENTITY_SUCCESS:
      case actions.UPDATE_ENTITY_SUCCESS: {
        const EntityDetails = action.payload;
        const entities = {
          ...state.entities,
          [Entitydetails.Id]: EntityDetails,
        };
        return {
          ...state,
          error: null,
          entities,
        };
      }
      default : {
        return state;
      }
    }
 }
```

Previously, my code did not have a `default` condition, and was returning `undefined` due to that fact. adding the `default` condition to the reducer resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar usecase. Your attempt is good, and I got it working this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class PatientService {
  // Define Observable
  patientState$: Observable<PatientState>;
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {
    // Get data from the store
    this.patientState$ = store.select<PatientState>('patients');
  }

  getState(): PatientState {
    // subscribe to it so i don't have to deal with observables in components
    let patientState: PatientState = null;
    this.patientState$.subscribe(ps => patientState = ps);
    return patientState;
  }
}
```

Now you are able to call this method from any component you want like that:

```
@Component({
  ...
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  patientState = new PatientState;
  constructor(
    private patientService: PatientService,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Simply get the Object from the store without dealing with observables
    this.patientState = this.patientService.getState();
  }

}
```

I use the `$` at the end of observables so I know every time I touch a variable if it is a Observable or not, this way I don't get confused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I ended up with a very similar approach.

Comment: This is a very bad design: 1. A service is not meant to store any state, that what the store does. If many components use the same service, your service's state will be messed up.  2. Following this approach it's impossible to clean up the subscription (unsubscribe when the job is done or the component is destroyed). If you don't do that then your application could get memory leaks.

Comment: My advice is to forget about what you guys are trying to do and don't try to reinvent the wheel. Follow strictly the good practice https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app/app

Comment: I have yet to have an issue by encapsulating the store on a singleton service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a this reference,

```
this.state = store.select<PatientState>('patients');
```

should be

```
this.state = this.store.select<PatientState>('patients');
```

Comment: Meta: While Stack Exchange supports markdown, they do unfortunately not support three backticks for codeblocks. So when you answer with code, indent with at least four spaces instead. Single backticks are supported for inline codeblocks, but full code blocks require spaces.

Comment: "this" reference is optional here as store is also constructor method parameter at the same time as class property (because it is defined as property on compilation)